# Mantener una misma sesion para dos proyectos laravel en subdominios

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera crear dos proyectos laravel en dos subdominios en un mismo servidor,

por ej:

- **app1.dominio.com**
- **app2.dominio.com**

Seria con una misma base datos, Lo que quisiera es que al loguearse en una aplicacion, se refleje tambien logueado si ingresa en la otra aplicacion.

Como podria hacer esto con Laravel 5.4?

Comment: crea un login independiente, cuando inicies sesion envia esos datos a ambas app, dices que manejas la misma base de datos para las dos, puedes poner una condicion en tu login que cuando inicie sesion el status de el usuario se torne a true y asi cuando entres a las apps consultes si esta iniciada sesion y puedas entrar a ambas.

Comment: ¿con la misma instancia de Laravel?

Comment: @Exbaby Lo que quisiera es que al loguearme un subdominio, y luego vaya al otro subdominio ya tendria que estar logueado

Comment: podrias usar OAuth

Comment: @RicardoD.Quiroga OAuth seria compartir información sobre sus cuentas con aplicaciones de terceros o sitios web.

Comment: @Shaz con instancias distintas, dos proyectos distintos

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de solucionar esto, dependiendo los detalles de cada escenario, pero tal vez la forma más común es modificar el dominio en config.php:

**app/config.php**

```
domain => '.dominio.com'
```

Posterior a esto, hay que limpiar las cookies previamente almacenadas para dichos sitios.

---

Otra forma, tal vez menos ortodoxa pero igualmente sencilla en caso que tengas una sola instancia de Laravel para los dos subdominios, es simplemente dirigir ambos archivos `public/index.php` a la misma instancia, algo así:

En el contenido de ambos archivos, reemplazar las siguientes dos líneas hacia la misma instancia de Laravel, o en otras palabras hacia el mismo directorio `bootstrap`:

**app1.dominio.com/index.php** y **app2.dominio.com/index.php**

```
// Línea 22
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

// Línea 36
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: cree los subdominios en mi servidor local para probar dos subdominios.. app1.dominio.com y app2.dominio.com luego en config/session.php 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'), luego en  'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.dominio.com'), esto no me funciona no mantiene la cesion, ya cree los subdominios en el virtual host

Answer (score 0):

Creo que las sessiones son únicas de un dominio especifico. aun busco en la documentación de PHP donde hable sobre eso...

Te recomendaría utilizar otra estrategia para hacer esto.

como por ejemplo **tokens** que puedas intercambiar entre los dominios.

Comment: Todavia sigo investigando agradeceria tu ayuda

Comment: Te escribo otra respuesta, voy a redactarla bien antes de colocarla.

Comment: Aguardo tu respuesta @Luis gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Sistema de autenticación mediante **tokens** en varias plataformas *laravel*

Prerequisitos:

- **Api** o sistema de alimentación mediante peticiones *HTTP* *GET | POST*
- manejo fluido de *web storage* de **HTML5**

Para los logins que quieres unificar tienes que agregar un manejador de *[web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)*.

Cuando inicies session en tu aplicación, guardas el *token* que debe estar de igual forma en un **DB** en el web sotrage.

> Esto con la intencion de comparar el token del cliente con el de la DB.

Entonces, cuando estés en el login de tus aplicaciones busca esta variable con JS y la mandas por medio de AJAX al servidor, si este **Token** es valido solo haces la redirección correspondiente y en ese redireccionamiento guardas tus datos de session que necesites.

> En esta redireccion puedes mandar otra vez el token, para que puedas buscar al usuario dueño, y asi cargar a la session los datos que necesites...

Esto es mas o menos iguala *Recuerdame*

Espero te ayude, Si tienes preguntas. Con gusto te ayudo...

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la tabla se sesiones en laravel, en este caso, la aplicación que loguea debiese ser laravel y compartir este inicio de sesión en la aplicación 2 por medio de la tabla de la base de datos, esto es bueno pues puedes usar varios dominios para poder loguean entre ellos

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session

en la configuración debes poner database o el SESSION_DRIVER del .env y en la opción, de la sección Session Cookie Name en el archivo config/session.php colocar un nombre identico y usar ese mismo nombre de coockie en el proyecto 2 en caso que sean proyectos de laravel, si fuese otro tiempo solo debes usar el login de la base de datos de laravel, mira el link que deje arriba.